# QLabel: interlinea/linespacing in WordWrap mode

Tags: qt, qt4

How do I set line height in QLabel when in WordWrap mode?

Comment: the two properties are not related.

Comment: QLabel has wordwrap mode. The question is how to set lineheight

Answer (score 9):

Use HTML text:

```
QString template = "<p style=\"line-height:%1%\">%2<p>";
QString targetText = template.arg(myPercentage).arg(myTex);
QLabel *l = new QLabel(targetText, this);
```

where myPercentage is like 60 - 80.
You will get condensed lines in the WordWrap mode

Comment: One problem though: `template` is a bad name for a variable in C++

Answer (score 5):

There is no line spacing property in `QLabel`. You can change the widget font, which will change the line's height, but I suspect that is not what you want.

Line height is computed from the `QFont` of the widget and can be obtained by the `QFontMetrics` associated with the widget. Using this information, you may create your own widget that has a line spacing property (and a text wrap mode), but that represents a lot of low-level work.

Answer (score 5):

You can also edit the HTML of the `QLabel` directly in Qt Designer.

- Select the label in Qt Designer.
- In the Property Editor, under the `QLabel` section, select the `text` property and press the `...` button.
- Select the "source" tab and edit the HTML from there.

Here are two examples that control the line spacing of a `QLabel` using HTML (tested in Qt 5.7). I am sure there are many more (and some better) ways to write the HTML, but this should be a good start.

**Example 1**

```
<html><head/><body>
<p style="line-height:120"><span>
This is the first line of the label.<br>
This is the second line.<br>
This is the third and final line.
</span></p>
</body></html>
```

This example is neater if the line spacing is the same for the whole paragraph.

**Example 2**

```
<html><head/><body>
<p style="line-height:20"><span>This is the first line of the label.</span></p>
<p style="line-height:20"><span>This is the second line.</span></p>
<p style="line-height:100"><span>This is the third and final line.</span></p>
</body></html>
```

This example allows you to control the spacing of each line individually. I had to make the height of the last line 100 to prevent Qt from cutting it in half. I assume it affects how Qt calculates the height of the label as a widget.